# How to check if gremlin is properly connected to aws neptune instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-vpc, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I have launched an aws neptune instance and installed *apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console* version 3.3.3 on windows 10 machine.

neptune-remote.yml looks like:

```
hosts: [abc-nept.XXXXXX.us-XXXX-1.neptune.amazonaws.com]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

after running *gremlin.bat* next command is:

> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/neptune-remote.yaml

Now at this stage I am able to make queries and those are working! So question is how can I check whether I am actually **connected to aws neptune instance or not?**

Comment: sorry if i'm not understanding, but if you are sending queries and getting results back what other confirmation of connectivity are you looking for?

Comment: Because I need to double check whether data is going to Aws or on local tinkerpop server. I am new to it so not sure about how to confirm either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your question is related to having multiple `:remote` instances configured. Obviously, if you've simply created:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/neptune-remote.yaml
```

then the only place your data could be going to or coming from is Neptune. The Console does allow multiple `:remote` instance that you can switch between so if you also had one for a local Gremlin Server then you might want to confirm which one you're sending requests. You just do this:

```
gremlin> :remote
==>Remote - Gremlin Server - [localhost/127.0.0.1:8182]
```

You'll be able to see the "current" `:remote` and thus know whether it is for Neptune or your local Gremlin Server instance.

Comment: oh! thank you for the answer, in fact I did that too every before post the question but didn't have confidence on it :) now it brings up another confusion how it is connect if I am not in same vpc because as per aws-neptune docs it can only be access if resource is in same vpc and region either ec2 or aws-lambda.

Comment: you might have to ask a new question for that one or consult amazon support directly....i don't know the answer to that one unfortunately.

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon Is there anything else you were looking for with regards to this question?

Comment: @KarthikRajan I think, the solution was to configure ec2 with neptune and then connect to ec2 and tunneling helped to make sure queries are going to neptune

Comment: @KarthikRajan another problem is how to write graphson (v3) to neptune using lambda (node.js or python)?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon Can you capture the details of that in a separate question?